# Telegram bot and google apps script not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, bots, telegram

Good evening everyone, forgive the trouble, I tried to do a "search" on the site but I could not find the answer to my problem so I thought of opening a new discussion.
I make two premises, the first is that I am not familiar with the English language and therefore I am writing to you via google translator, the second is that I am a novice programmer.
Having said that, let's get to the tricky part immediately, the following is the code that I put by inserting the token and the webappurl

```
var token = "YOUR_TOKEN";
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "YOUR_YO_URL";

function setWebhook () {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/ setWebhook? url =" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch (url);
}

function sendMessage (chat_id, text) {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/ sendMessage? chat_id =" + chat_id + "& text =" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch (url);
}

function doPost (e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse (e.postData.contents);
  var chat_id = contents.message.from.id;
  var answer = "Hello";
  sendMessage (chat_id, answer);
}
```

once this is done I publish it as a web application
I imposed that a new version
Execute the app as my account
Who has access to the app anyone
and press on update
i go to my telegram bot and any message i send does not reply to me.
I also tried to follow other tutorials (the codes are very similar to each other) but always the same story, I follow the procedures, but when I go to write on the bot it gives me no sign of life.
I thank all those who want to help me
and I apologize for what for the more experienced will be a very simple problem
Thank you

---

I added the line of code you suggested to me

```
function setWebhook () {
   var url = telegramUrl + "/ setWebhook? url =" + webAppUrl;
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch (url);
   Logger.log (response.getContentText ());
}
```

the result was the following

```
"[22-03-25 19: 00: 07: 208 CET] {" ok ": true," result ": true," description ":" Webhook is already set "}"
```

but my bot still keeps not responding.

Comment: Try logging the response to the `setWebhook()` function to see if that worked. You can use `Logger.log(response.getContentText());`

Comment: You never call any of those functions?

Answer (score 0):

you have no wrong in your code , you just need to deploy the web app using the old version of Google apps script to go to the old version find this and click on it

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXPd4.png)

then deploy it

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8AhX.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR6Ik.png)

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hB7f.png)

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B1Rm.png)

after u get the appurl use it in ur code and deploy it againe .
after that go back to the new version of google app script , and every time you make changes and want to deploy use manage deployments

[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW6Gl.png)

[7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmKHy.png)

**and you can contact me on telegram to help you , my username : @zedkrimo**